# CSS3 animations delay issue

Tags: html, css, delay, css-animations

I have three images in my html file that I want to scale **one at a time**. I've tried placing these delays: `-moz-animation-delay: -2s;` and `animation-delay:2s;` within the ID `#animation-container2` and `#animation-container3`. All the images still scale at the same time. What am I doing incorrectly?

The html

```
<div id="splashPage">
     <ul>
     <li>   <img src="images/vintage.png" alt="Vintage" id="animation-container"> <li>
     <li>   <img src="images/computers.png" alt="Computer" id="animation-container2"> <li>
     <li>   <img src="images/online.png" alt="Online" id="animation-container3" > <li>
     </ul>
     <img src="images/enter.gif" alt="enter" id="enterClick"> 
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#animation-container {
  animation: inout 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 3s; /* Safari & Chrome */
  margin: auto;
}
@keyframes inout {
  25%   { transform: scale(2, 2); }
}
#animation-container2 {
  -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation: inout 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 3s; /* Safari & Chrome */
  margin: auto;
}
@keyframes inout {
  25%   { transform: scale(2, 2); }
}
#animation-container3 {
  -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation: inout 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 3s; /* Safari & Chrome */
  margin: auto;
}
@keyframes inout {
  25%   { transform: scale(2, 2); }
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger the animation?  Why not start the 2nd animation when the first finishes?  and so on?

Comment: 1. Can you create a [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)? 2. You define the `inout` animation three times (one should be enough).

Comment: with jsfiddle whats the best way to upload the images?

Comment: @DMS You can use dummy images from something like http://dummyimage.com/

Comment: @Inkbug http://jsfiddle.net/vrLUc/1/       http://jsfiddle.net/vrLUc/1/embedded/result/    it doesn't scale at all on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some new and cleaner CSS that should work:

```
#animation-container {
  animation: inout 2s 0s 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 2s 0s 1;
  margin: auto;
}
#animation-container2 {
  animation: inout 2s 5s 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 2s 5s 1;
  margin: auto;
}
#animation-container3 {
  animation: inout 2s 10s 1;
  -webkit-animation: inout 2s 10s 1;
  margin: auto;
}
@keyframes inout {
  25%   { transform: scale(2, 2); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inout {
  25%   { -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2); }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrLUc/2/).